# Hierarchical mixed-effects models notation

Tags: mixed-model, notation, nested-models

I have a hierarchical mixed-effects model where observations i, from group S_2 (representing municipalities), are nested inside group S_1 (representing states), which in turn are nested inside N (representing countries). Here is the notation I used to describe this model:

[image]

I based this notation on some references I found but I am not sure if I am representing the hierarchical structure (in red) the right way.

I am also calling δ_(NS_1 S_2 ) and θ_(NS_1 S_2 ) as "design matrices" but is this the right term to use?

Any references or feedback are appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly going two or more levels down, can lead to an indexing spaghetti but I think your notation is fine. The only obvious issue for me is that you $i$ at the front where it should be something like $N,S1,S2,i$. I would suggests looking at some papers on "Four-level hierarchical models" to get some further ideas on how to properly notate things. (e.g. *[Latent Variable Regression Four-Level Hierarchical Model Using Multisite Multiple-Cohort
Longitudinal Data](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.3102/1076998619864538)* (2018) by Choi and Kim) Finally a standard way to refer to the matrices denoting the grouping hierarchy is "random-effects design matrix" - usually denoted with $Z$ (to distinguish it from the "fixed-effects design matrix" - usually denoted with $X$).